# WooCommerce REST API The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized VB.NET

Tags: wordpress, vb.net

My site (https://www.trs.is) recently switched to https and now I am getting an Unauthorized error when I try to get all products from my WooCommerce store. I have tried many things with the WebClient() to use basic authentication but I always get this error.

I have also tested this with Postman from Google with basic auth and using the client key and client secret but the error is always the same.

Scratching my head here and after hours of searching I can not see why the this is happening.

Here is my latest code (actual client keys are removed)

```
Dim url As String = "https://www.trs.is/wc-api/v3/products"
        'Dim client As New WebClient()
        Dim userName As [String] = "myclientkey"
        Dim passWord As [String] = "myclientsecret"

        'client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, passWord)

        Dim credentials As String = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName + ":" + passWord))
        wc.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization) = Convert.ToString("Basic") & credentials

        Dim result = wc.DownloadString(url)
```

Any help guys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `wc.UseDefaultCredentials = True` and post your API keys instead.

Comment: Not working... still the same error

But like I said previously I can't figure out why the Postman is not working either.  Are there some username and password credentials I'm not aware of here ?

Comment: O my god ! I just realized that the URL I had was not correct due to updates in the REST API for WooCommerce.

I have updated the URL to https://www.trs.is/wp-json/wc/v1/products

But now I get this error

{
  "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
  "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}

Comment: @GrétarMagnússon Then is this question answered?